# Как задать фиксированную локальную папку для сохранения файла при вызове PHP функции readfile?

Tags: php

Есть zip файл с именем $zip_name, надо его сохранить в пользовательскую локальную папку, которая им предварительно была определена.
Как это сделать?

При отработке следующего кода:

```
  header("Content-type: application/zip");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_name");
  readfile($zip_name);
```

показывается диалог, в котором папка для сохранения выбирается каким-то неизвестным мне методом.
Ее конечно можно изменить, но хотелось бы, чтобы уже была выбрана какая-то предварительно заданная папка.
Можно ли это сделать и если да, то как?

Comment: А если этой папки нет у пользователя на компьютере?

Comment: Какой этой? Это уже ответственность пользователя. Он конечно же должен был в настройках задачи задать папку, которая есть. Ну, если вдруг ее нет, то да, ее можно создать. Но вопрос не в этом, а в том, как в принципе подставить пользовательскую папку.

Comment: @InDevX тут речь про директорю на клиентской стороне пользователя.

Comment: никак вы не сможете повлиять, на что там будет в диалоговом окне сохранения файла у пользователя. Единственное, что может вас порадовать, то что современные браузеры вроде запоминают, куда вы сохраняли контент с этой страницы в прошлый раз, и при последующем сохранении откроют ранее выбранную папку.

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант действительно работает - выбирается последняя папка. Но все-таки мне кажется, что должен быть какой-то способ, во всяком случае в других системах, с которыми я работал - C#, CenturaTeamDeveloper аналогичная функция предоставляет такую возможность. Странно было бы, что в PHP ее нет.

Comment: @Павел PHP здесь вообще не причём. Это невозможно сделать в принципе на уровне HTTP. Пускай сайт хоть на java написан, хоть на C#, хоть на питоне, так сделать невозможно

Comment: Ну oK, невозможно так невозможно, верю экспертному мнению. Хотя, конечно жаль, сервис будет не вполне дружественный. Когда я говорил об аналогичных функциях, речь шла не о браузерных задачах

Comment: в десктопных приложениях, конечно, такие настройки имеют место быть. сайт же не может на подобное влиять никак, тут в принципе любой доступ к локальной файловой системе запрещен по соображениям безопасности.